# Visual Studio Express C# or Java and Netbeans, or something else...?

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio, netbeans

I want to start to work on one application. I wonder if it is better to work in Visual Studio Express version in C#, or to use Netbeans and Java, an open soruce IDE?

I plan to this program may one day be commercial and that can be downloaded from the Internet.

Comment: First choose your platform and then choose the development environment.

Comment: If you had included some requirements, programming experience etc it might have been a question.

Comment: I have experience with VS and C#, database, ADO.NET... I also have experience with Java, syntax is not a problem. My question is because I am not sure how many limitation VS Express has, that is reason why I am asking this question.

Comment: Visual Studio Express has no limitations on Commercial use. Express is missing some features compared to Professional, but not any that I believe to be generally detrimental.

Comment: My question is more about IDE, because I will be use VS Express and I am not sure is it than better to go with Java and some another IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include more information. Posts like this usually result in a [flame war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaming_%28Internet%29). Firstly, if your application is supposed to target only Windows and nothing else, then C# may be an option, otherwise, it has to be completely command line or run without errors on Mono and Visual Studio (easier said than done, considering there is no WPF in Mono as of yet.)

If this your first language, I would recommend neither. They are both quite difficult to begin with and you will get stuck in the syntax, instead I would recommend [Python](http://python.org). It will get you up to speed quickly, and then you can move on to maybe Java or C#.

Java and C# are very similar. Here are some differences:

- C# has a more advanced object system (delegates, closures, etc.)
- Java is completely cross platform
- C# has a less of an open source community around it
- Java is slow in implementing new things
- C#'s popularity is rising ([TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html)
- Java's popularity is falling

In the end, you decide.

Comment: I am not new to programming. As I sad, my question is more about IDE, because I am thinking to use VS Express and I am not sure is it maybe better to go with Java and some another IDE because VS Express limitations.

Comment: You're comparing two things at once, I think. If you would like to use C#, and its to your advantage you can use VS Express (I've been using it without fault for a while), however, if you want Java, you have a range of IDEs to select from (I would recommend netbeans). Also, for C#, you have sharpdevelop.

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with your preference. C# and Java share a lot of similarities in syntax and structure. What current programming background do you posses? If you're new to programming, maybe the development environment of Visual Studio for you would be easier to start with, plus there's a vast amount of information on the net for C#, compared to Java.

At the end what you should choose is the platform, as there are multiple Dev. tools you can choose to program in the desired language.

Comment: -1. C# doesn't necessarily have more docs. And, don't spell Java like that, its like spelling Perl like PERL.

Comment: Already corrected it :P I actually belive C# have more community generated articles for getting started with, which is why Java would have a more dificult learning curve for a *new* programmer. As for someone with experience, both should be easy to pick up.

I also believe C# is evolving faster. Of course, one of the biggest drawbacks is that it's not as open, and it's not cross platform.